# Showing $\psi \colon G \rightarrow G$ is bijective requires only showing injectivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is from a past paper. I will write the question in full, but it is only one step I do not understand (the first step):

"Let $G$ be a finite abelian subgroup. Let $\psi \colon G \rightarrow G$ be given by $\psi(g)=g^2$. Show that if $|G|$ is odd, then $\psi$ is bijective."

Then the first step given in the explanatory solution is:

"Since $\psi$ is a function from the finite set $G$ to itself, it's sufficient to show that $\psi$ is injective".

However I cannot see how the above statement follows simply from knowing that $\psi$ is a function from $G$ to $G$.

Thanks

Comment: You can look at this graphically with venn diagrams and arrows between them. After you have made |G| choices of arrows such that the function is injective, every element must have been hit exactly once.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57913/suppose-that-g-is-a-finite-nonabelian-group-with-odd-order-show-s-is-surjectiv?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is finite and $\psi\colon G\longrightarrow G$ is an injective function, then $\#\psi(G)=\#G$ (because $\psi$ is injective). But the only subset of $G$ with $\#G$ elements is $G$ itself. Therefore $\psi(G)=G$. In other words, $\psi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the elements of $G$ be $\{g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_{2n+1}\}$. Now let $\exists~g\in G$, $g\ne e$, such that $g^2=e$. Then consider the set $A=\{g_1g,g_2g,\cdots,g_{2n+1}g\}\subseteq G$. Now if $g_ig=g_jg$, the post multiplying with $g^{-1}$ on both sides we get $g_i=g_j$. So all the elements of $A$ are distinct and $|A|=|G|$. So $A=G$. However $g_ig=g_j\implies g_i=g_jg$, so there are an even number of elements in $A$, contradictory to our assumption. So there cannot exist a $g\ne e$ in $G$ such that $g^2=e$. Hence $\psi$ is an isomorphism.